# Java Card - Applet selection failed

Tags: applet, smartcard, javacard

Below is DES encryption code. I am getting error 0x6999: "Applet selection failed".

```
package JCardDES;

import javacard.framework.*;
import javacard.security.*;
import javacardx.crypto.*;

public class JCard_DES extends Applet
{
     // globals
     DESKey deskey;
     Cipher cipherCBC;
     final short dataOffset = (short) ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA;
     static byte[] TrippleDESKey = {(byte) 0x38, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0xA4,
          (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0xC6, (byte) 0x3B, (byte) 0xE7, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x00,
          (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x3B, (byte) 0xE7, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x01,
          (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0xE7, (byte) 0x71};

     // constructor,
     // initialization
     private JCard_DES(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
     {
          try {
             deskey = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES3_3KEY, false);
             cipherCBC = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, false);
          }
          catch (CryptoException e) {
             ISOException.throwIt((short) ((short) 0x9000 + e.getReason()));
          }

          if (bArray[bOffset] == 0) 
          {
               register();
          }
          else 
          {
               register(bArray, (short)(bOffset+1), bArray[bOffset]);
          }
     }

     // install
     public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
     {
          new JCard_DES(bArray, bOffset, bLength);
     }

     public void process(APDU apdu)
     {
          byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();

          if (selectingApplet())
          {
               return;
          }

          doTrippeDES(apdu);
     }

     // DES encryption
     private void doTrippeDES(APDU apdu)
     {
          byte a[] = apdu.getBuffer();

          short incomingLength = (short) (apdu.setIncomingAndReceive());
          if (incomingLength != 24) ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_LENGTH);

          deskey.setKey(TrippleDESKey, (short)0);
          cipherCBC.init(deskey, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT,new byte[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},(short)0,(short)8);
          cipherCBC.doFinal(a, (short) dataOffset, incomingLength, a, (short) (dataOffset + 24));
          cipherCBC.init(deskey, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT,new byte[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},(short)0,(short)8);
          cipherCBC.doFinal(a, (short) (dataOffset + 24), incomingLength, a, (short) (dataOffset + 48));

          // send results
          apdu.setOutgoing();
          apdu.setOutgoingLength((short) 72);
          apdu.sendBytesLong(a, (short) dataOffset, (short) 72);
     }
}
```

That's strange, because without the initialization codes in try/catch block, there is no problem to select the applet.

My script file (APDU script) is

```
powerup;
// Select JCard_DES
0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0X06 0XFC 0X74 0X41 0XA1 0X9B 0X63 0x7F;
```

Please guide me where i'm going wrong since i'm new to Java Card Programming

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your command length (Lc) is incorrect. It should be `0x07` instead of `0x06`.

```
0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0X07 0XFC 0X74 0X41 0XA1 0X9B 0X63 0x7F
```

Comment: If your data (AID) is 0XFC 0X74 0X41 0XA1 0X9B 0X63 0x7F, then your Lc / P3 should be 0x07 (7 bytes).

Comment: My DATA is 0XFC 0X74 0X41 0XA1 0X9B 0X63. 

CLA = 0x00 
INS = 0xA4 
P1 = 0x04 
P2 = 0x00 
LC = 0X06 
DATA = 0XFC 0X74 0X41 0XA1 0X9B 0X63 
LE = 0x7F

Comment: Lc is length of command data, Le is length of expected data. You can only send Lc or Le in single APDU. If your data/AID is 0XFC 0X74 0X41 0XA1 0X9B 0X63, then remove the last byte 0x7F from the APDU. After a successful response then you can send GET RESPONSE command with Le (usually the Le is equal to SW2 or ranging from 1 to SW2).

Comment: This is the result after I remove 0x7F from the APDU: 


Invoking apdutool on D:\IT\RISET\JAVA\NetBeansProjects\JCard_DES/scripts/jcard_des.scr 
... 
Input data length != Lc around line 5.

Comment: You definitly can have APDU with Lc and Le. Le=7F is very odd and I've never seen this. Just put in 0x00 for Le, this means: give back  whatever you have

Comment: This is the result if Le=0x00:
CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 06, fc, 74, 41, a1, 9b, 63, Le: 00, SW1: 69, SW2: 99
-> SW = 6999

Answer (score 0):

error code 0x6999 means applet selection failed.To determine the correctness of your aid and uniqueness.Pay attention to rules inside sometimes choose aid will appear automatically when the concept of completion.